# Ubuntu 12.04 random key presses and key presses not registering

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a problem with ubuntu 12.04 that started while using the <kbd>fn</kbd> and some of the <kbd>f1</kbd>...<kbd>f12</kbd> keys on my keyboard. All of a sudden my computer starts to "press" volume up and directly afterwards "long-presses" either E or W. It will also make a few of my own key-presses not respond. I have absolutely no clue as to why it does this but it makes programming a pain.

Specifications: Ubuntu 12.04 Lenovo thinkpad T430

Edit:
Think I found the problem and its solution.
http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/Problems-with-the-keyboard-T410/td-p/288630
It's most likely a Lenovo-specific issue

Comment: if everything is ok with your keyboard, why not upgrade to 12.10, or just boot 12.10 and try if everything is ok.

Comment: That has crossed my mind but I'd still like to know if this is something that anyone else has encountered.